# Consequences of Uninstall & Re-installing Ubuntu on Windows 8 via Virtual Box

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

LONG STORY SHORT, if I uninstalled Virtual Box + Ubuntu15.04 and Reinstalled them again on the same Windows Machine, will there be a problem. Will the previous install interfere ?

More....
I had a version of VirtualBox installed on my Windows8 machine & had Ubuntu15.04 installed in the VirtualBox. Im trying to progess with Laravel for Begineers, but Im having a nightmare of a time with the terminal. Error after another. My installation of Ubuntu was immature & had all the folders everywhere. Trouble with node & npm installs. Bugs are endless..

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machines if you wish.You do not have to uninstall VirtualBox.

I would suggest that you install another Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine (latest Ubuntu version) and copy files from old Ubuntu virtual machine to new Ubuntu virtual machine. After you copy files from old Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine and you have all setup up on new virtual machine, you can safely delete old Ubuntu 15.04 virtual machine.

You can copy files from one virtual machine to other using:

- virtualbox shared folders on both virtual machines, follow this
  [link](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/setup-virtualbox-shared-folders-linux-windows/) and this [link](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/mount-virtualbox-shared-folder-on-ubuntu-linux/)
- use USB stick - mount on old virtual machine using Devices > USB >
  [USB Stick], copy files, eject device, mount on new virtual machine
  Devices > USB > [USB Stick] and copy files